# Impossible to watch with compass: text file busy on shared folder

Tags: ruby, sass, debian, shared-directory

I installed RVM+Ruby+Sass+Compass on a Debian6 and now I am trying to "compass watch" on a shared folder through VirtualBox.
Host: Windows7
Guest: Debian6
Debian6 can write files on the Windows7 shared folder, it works fine this is not the problem.

```
#compass watch

Errno:: ETXTBSY on line 886 of /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass../sass/util.rb: Text file busy .... .sass-cache...
```

It managed to created a folder in .sass-cache but no files are created into it. With root or a standard user, I get this error.

I tried to install Ruby, alone or with RVM. No success.
My shared folder is mounted this way:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0 sites /var/www/sites
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 17):

I know the problem is very old but though no answer has been given yet, I just wanted to say I had the same problem and solved it by setting "cache_path" in the config.rb file to "/tmp/.sass-cache" so the vboxsf will not be used.